# Calculating the complexity of Levenshtein Edit Distance

Tags: python, algorithm, complexity-theory, dynamic-programming, levenshtein-distance

I have been looking at this simple python implementation of [Levenshtein Edit Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for all day now.

```
def lev(a, b):
    """Recursively calculate the Levenshtein edit distance between two strings, a and b.
    Returns the edit distance.
    """
    if("" == a):
        return len(b)   # returns if a is an empty string
    if("" == b):
        return len(a)   # returns if b is an empty string
    return min(lev(a[:-1], b[:-1])+(a[-1] != b[-1]), lev(a[:-1], b)+1, lev(a, b[:-1])+1)
```

From: http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp130/12spring/editdist/

I know it has an exponential complexity, but how would I proceed to calculate that complexity from scratch?

I have been searching all over the internet but haven't found any explainations only statements that it is exponential.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to draw a call tree. Usually, this is solved with dynamic programming/memoization.

Comment: I have already done that but I can't find a connection between the number of nodes and exponential growth

Comment: This naive implementation is exponential, but the algorithm doesn't have to be. Memoization makes this polynomial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Draw the call tree (which you apparently have already done).
2. Abstract from the call tree. For arbitrary *n*, determine the depth *d* of the tree as a function of *n*.

   Also, determine how many branches/children there are per node, on average, as *n* approaches infinity; that's called the average branching factor *b*.
3. Realize that visiting every node in a tree of depth *d* with average branching factor *b* takes at least on the order of *b* ^ *d* operations. Write that figure in terms of *n* and you have a lower bound on complexity in terms of the input size.

More specifically: you keep recursing until you hit an empty string, taking one character off each time. If we call the lengths of the strings *m* and *n*, then the depth of the tree is min(*m*, *n*). At every node in the call tree except the leaves, you recurse exactly three times, so in the limit the average branching factor is 3. That gives us a call tree of Θ(3^min(*m*, *n*)) nodes. The worst case occurs when *m* = *n*, so we can call that Θ(3^*n*).

This is still only a lower bound on the complexity. For the full picture, you should also take into account the amount of work done between recursive calls. In this naive code, that's actually *linear time* because `a[:-1]` has to copy (at Θ(*n*) cost) almost all of `a`, giving Θ(*n* 3^*n*) total complexity.*

[* I once caught a CS professor using Python's slicing in a binary search, which as a result ran in time Θ(*n* lg *n*).]

Comment: Thank you mate, that was the best explaination of the problem I have seen.