# Proportional or Constant Complexity?

Tags: algorithm, constants, computer-science, complexity-theory, recurrence

I have been given a algorithm about The Levenshtein distance between two character strings  and  is defined as the minimum number of single-character insertions, deletions, or substitutions (so-called edit operations) required to transform string  into string .
The algorithm in pseudo code is:
[image]

I have counted the number of recursive calls which is 3 and number of elements is N - 2 (since function () of the total number  ≔  +  of input characters). So I got the recurrence as T(N) = 3T(N-2) + dN. But I'm not sure it could be constant d or proportional dN. Using the Master Theorem, I got 2^(N log(3)) with base is 4. I need some help to get the right recurrence for the worst case, and how to determine dN or d.
Thank you.``

Answer (score 0):

It is constant.

That part of the formula is not dependent on  as the algorithm only needs to access , , [1] and [1] at that stage, so we can just use a constant  or even 1 for it (it doesn't matter). The other comparisons that will follow in recursion are covered by the recursive part of the relation.

A few considerations:

- The recursive part of the formula is not *exactly* as you say. It is true that the worst case when  > 0 and  > 0 is when [1] and [1] are different, so we get in the min part of the formula. But there we have two recursive calls that reduce  with just 1 (not 2).
- Simplifying the relation by just using  instead of  and  hides the fact that the recursion will **in most cases** not continue until  is 1, but will abort for some greater value of  because at that time a base case kicks in, with =0 or =0. If the purpose is only to find an *upper bound* for the complexity this is of course not a problem.

See also [Calculating the complexity of Levenshtein Edit Distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628753/calculating-the-complexity-of-levenshtein-edit-distance).